# SurfaceView crash

Tags: android, surfaceview

In my app I randomly get the following crash:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:498)
android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:412)
android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:89)
android.view.SurfaceView$1.handleMessage(SurfaceView.java:131)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

(Android 2.3.6)

Does anyone have a clue on how to debug it ?

Note that I need to do some weird stuff on my surface to keep it alive when being detached from hierarchy, like:

```
    private boolean detachFromParent = false;

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        if(detachFromParent) {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        if(getParent() != null) {
            detachFromParent = true;
            ((ViewGroup) getParent()).removeView(this);
            detachFromParent = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you get still get the errors when you dont do these weird things?

Comment: don't know...these errors were reported by users but I can't manage to reproduce it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at [line 498  on the android source (for 2.3.6)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-2.3.6_r0.9/core/java/android/view/SurfaceView.java) for SurfaceView yields:

```
visible ? VISIBLE : GONE, false, mWinFrame, mContentInsets,
```

One of these is null,  I'm guessing those weird things you are doing is making this code run with mWinFrame value of null.

Can you provide some more detail as to why your not letting the view detach normally? I know you must have a reason. Otherwise, I'd blindly recommend taking it out and afford your intended actions some other way (code it differently).

If you have a Nexus S you could try to debug the issue yourself and figure out the exact root cause of the problem and fix it (stack traces are your friend).  [Here is a link to instructions on downgrading a Nexus S to 2.3.6](http://kishanrathod.blogspot.com/2011/12/downgrade-nexus-s-from-403-to-236.html)

Comment: I also came up with this line...but even if any of mWinFrame or mContentInsets was null that should not throw a NullPointerException at this point...right ? So I guess there must be a line shift for some reason

Comment: Btw I needed this hack to keep a video playing across activities or orientation changes

Comment: Ahh I see,  might be better to use fragments and a single activity then?  And also maybe, override config changes for that Activity's orientation change to avoid the destroy?

Comment: Well I may explore other solutions later but so far I was curious to find out the source of this crash

Comment: get a nexus s, downgrade, and repro the bug.  You'll get it.